# javascript how match whole words but in certain length limit

Tags: javascript, regex, match, string-length

for example i have this two strings:

string1:

```
"hi sir may name is Jone"
```

string2

```
 "hi may name is Jone"
```

i have this this regex:

```
     var regex = XRegExp('hi(?:(?!hi|Jone).)*?Jone', 'gs');
```

will match both of them but i want to modify the regex to match only in limited length of the whole string

i want to match the string two "hi may name is Jone" as had less words length how to do it..

Comment: `hi\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,3}Jone` will only allow 1 to 3 other words between the "hi" and "Jone".

Comment: Why don't you check length of string before applying regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the string with the least amount of words that also matches your regex, you could [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and use a whitespace as a separator and check the length of the returned array.

As an example with an array of strings, you could create `var longestString = "";` which will at the end of the loop contain the shortest matched string.

In the loop, first check if there is a [match](http://xregexp.com/api/#match) and if `longestString` is an empty string. If that is the case then set the variable so you have a match to compare against future possible matches.

```js
var strings = [
  "test",
  "hi sir may name is Jone",
  "hi may name is Jone",
  "hi Jone",
  "hi may name is Jone test",
  "hi i am Jone",
  "may name is Jone test",
  "hi may name is Jane test test 2"
];

var regex = /hi(?:(?!hi|Jone).)*?Jone/;
var longestString = "";

strings.forEach((str) => {
  var match = XRegExp.match(str, regex);
  if (match && longestString === "") {
    longestString = str;
    return;
  }
  if (match && str.split(" ").length < longestString.split(" ").length) {
    longestString = str;
  }
});
console.log(longestString);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a limited length of the whole string using only regex, I think you can do something like this:

```
var index = 15;


var testString1 = "hi may name is Jone";
var testString2 = "hi sir may name is Jone";

testString1.match("^.{1," + index + "}Jone"); // This will match
testString2.match("^.{1," + index + "}Jone"); // This string is longer and will not match
```

Explanation of the regex `^.{1, n}Jone`.

`^` : should match the start of the string.

`.{1, n}Jone` : matches everything between 1 to `n` until the pattern is fully matched.

In this case we define the `n` as `index` so this "limit" can be dynamic.

Hope this helps!